# How do I check if string is a file contents or path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method that receives a string. It can accept a file path or contents of the file.

When I pass path, it reads it and processes it, all good.

When I pass contents, it crashes with `string contains null byte` when it check if a file path exists

Here is the part of the code that checks if passed param is a file:

```
contents = File.exists?(param) ? File.read(param) : param
```

My question is: Is there another way to check if the `param` is a binary content vs path without `File.exists?`

Comment: Worth noting... This code screams "potential security vulnerability!!!" to me. Of course, I do not know the wider context of how this is being used (so it may be fine), but what happens if a user submits the string: `/etc/password`?

Comment: @TomLord I'll just check if `param == '/etc/password'` and tell them politely not to try to hack me. Yeah, it's a back end system, `param` comes from a few internal code and never from the outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check if the string contains null bytes upfront:

```
contents = 
  case input
  when /\u0000/ then param
  when File.exists?(param) then File.read(param)
  else param
  end
```

Or, even easier, fall back to param unless `File#read` succeeded:

```
contents = File.read(param) rescue param
```